# Mapbox compile offline tool on Linux

Tags: c++, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am trying to compile the Mapbox GL [offline tool](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/bin) (mbgl-offline) on Linux to generate a database with offline data for a specific region.

Steps followed as posted in github repository to compile the offline tool on Linux but it failed:

- git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native.git
- cd mapbox-gl-native
- make offline (i tried also make mbgl-offline)
- compilation failed: Error message: make: *** No rule to make target 'offline'. Stop.

Any idea what is going wrong with compilation of the tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The README.md clearly states how to build Mapbox: [Developing](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native#developing)

You tried to compile it with `make`, but if you look around the repository there are a lot of `CMakeLists.txt`, which indicates that you should use CMake to compile it.

These are the steps I followed to build it:

```
git clone git@github.com:mapbox/mapbox-gl-native.git
cd mapbox-gl-native/
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

I also had to install two libraries in order to compile it. Depends on your setup what you need to install.

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libuv1-dev
```

Con't

```
cmake . -B build
cmake --build build -j 8
```

After you followed those steps you will have `build/bin/` which contains the built applications. You where searching for `build/bin/mbgl-offline`.